# Compare average - SPARQL

Tags: sparql

There is a dataset of users ranking movies. Need to find the users with similar taste to user1. Similar taste defined as follows: consider the average rank for `genre` from `user1` as `avgr1` and for the same genre from `user2` as `avgr2`, then `user1` and `user2` have similar taste is `abs(avgr1-avgr2)<1` . So far I was able to get the names, the genre and the absolute value between averages, but the filtering for comparison is not working.

```
SELECT ?p ?p1 ?genre (abs (AVG(?rating)-AVG(?ratingp1)) AS ?RDiff)
WHERE{
?p movies:hasRated ?rate.
?p1 foaf:knows ?p.
?rate movies:ratedMovie ?mov.
?rate movies:hasRating ?rating.
?mov movies:hasGenre ?genre.
?p1 movies:hasRated ?ratep1.
?ratep1 movies:ratedMovie ?movp1.
?ratep1 movies:hasRating ?ratingp1.
?movp1 movies:hasGenre ?genre.
FILTER (xsd:float(?Rdiff)<1.0 && ?p=movies:user1)
}
GROUP BY ?p ?p1 ?genre
```

Comment: In looking over your edit, it appears that you asked one question, and then my answer worked for it (since you incorporated it into this latest revision).  The latest revision seems to be asking a new question.  If you've found an answer to your original question, you mark an answer as accepted.  If you have a new question, you should post it as a new question, not edit the original.  By editing the original, you invalidate the answers that have been posted to it.  I've rolled back the question (but the revision is still available in the revision history).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very hard to answer these kinds of questions without some sample data to work with.  Here's some sample data that has two users who have similar rankings on comedy, but different rankings on romance:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>

:a :ranks [ :genre :comedy ; :value 2 ],
          [ :genre :comedy ; :value 3 ],
          [ :genre :comedy ; :value 3 ],
          [ :genre :romance ; :value 7 ],
          [ :genre :romance ; :value 8 ],
          [ :genre :romance ; :value 9 ].

:b :ranks [ :genre :comedy ; :value 3 ],
          [ :genre :comedy ; :value 3 ],
          [ :genre :comedy ; :value 4 ],
          [ :genre :romance ; :value 0 ],
          [ :genre :romance ; :value 1 ],
          [ :genre :romance ; :value 0 ].
```

Here's a query that computes the difference of their average rankings on genres:

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?user1 ?user2 ?genre (abs(avg(?value1)-avg(?value2)) as ?diff) {
  ?user1 :ranks [ :genre ?genre ; :value ?value1 ].
  ?user2 :ranks [ :genre ?genre ; :value ?value2 ].
  filter (str(?user1) < str(?user2)) #-- avoid duplicate user1/user2, user2/user1 results
}
group by ?user1 ?user2 ?genre
order by ?diff
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| user1 | user2 | genre    | diff                       |
=========================================================
| :a    | :b    | :comedy  | 0.666666666666666666666667 |
| :a    | :b    | :romance | 7.666666666666666666666667 |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, you can't **filter** on aggregate results, you have to use **having**, so to only take values where diff is less than some particular value, you'd do this:

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?user1 ?user2 ?genre (abs(avg(?value1)-avg(?value2)) as ?diff) {
  ?user1 :ranks [ :genre ?genre ; :value ?value1 ].
  ?user2 :ranks [ :genre ?genre ; :value ?value2 ].
  filter (str(?user1) < str(?user2))
}
group by ?user1 ?user2 ?genre
having (?diff < 1)
order by ?diff
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| user1 | user2 | genre   | diff                       |
========================================================
| :a    | :b    | :comedy | 0.666666666666666666666667 |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

If you don't care about the actual diff, except that it's below the threshold, you can put the expression in the **having** directly, and do:

```sql
select ?user1 ?user2 ?genre {
  #-- ...
}
group by ?user1 ?user2 ?genre
having (abs(avg(?value1)-avg(?value2)) < 1)
```

Comment: @nlimits But did this answer work for you?  There are differences in how to retrieve the actual rankings, but clearly understand how to do that part (since you have an existing query).  The part about **group by** and **having** should translate over pretty easily, yes?

Answer (score 0):

?Rdiff is not defined in the FILTER - the happens before the AS in the SELECT.

Try using HAVING which goes after the GROUP BY.