# Optimize SPARQL Query

Tags: sparql

I have query that finds similar tastes in movies. Such that the absolute value of difference between average rankings of users over same genre is less that 1:

```
SELECT ?p ?p1 ?genre
WHERE{
?p movies:hasRated ?rate.
?p1 foaf:knows ?p.
?rate movies:ratedMovie ?mov.
?rate movies:hasRating ?rating.
?mov movies:hasGenre ?genre.
?p1 movies:hasRated ?ratep1.
?ratep1 movies:ratedMovie ?movp1.
?ratep1 movies:hasRating ?ratingp1.
?movp1 movies:hasGenre ?genre.
FILTER (?p=movies:user1)
}
GROUP BY ?p ?p1 ?genre
HAVING (abs (AVG(?rating)-AVG(?ratingp1))<1.0)
```

I would like to ask, whether is it possible to optimize it ? As it looks so bad(

Here is part of  the dataset, where it will be used:

```
movies:Man_of_steel movies:hasGenre "action", "thriller" .

movies:Elysium movies:hasGenre "drama", "sci-fi" .

movies:Gravity movies:hasGenre "sci-fi", "drama" .

movies:Django_Unchained movies:hasGenre "thriller", "action" .

movies:user1 movies:hasGender "male" ;
           movies:hasAge "30"^^xsd:float ;
           movies:hasRated movies:Rating1, movies:Rating2 .

movies:Rating1 movies:ratedMovie movies:Gravity ;
               movies:hasRating "4.0"^^xsd:float .

movies:Rating2 movies:ratedMovie movies:Django_Unchained ;
               movies:hasRating "9.0"^^xsd:float .

movies:user2 movies:hasGender "female" ;
             movies:hasAge "27"^^xsd:float ;
             movies:hasRated movies:Rating3, movies:Rating4 ;
             foaf:knows movies:user1 .

movies:Rating3 movies:ratedMovie movies:Elysium ;
               movies:hasRating "3.0"^^xsd:float .

movies:Rating4 movies:ratedMovie movies:Gravity ;
               movies:hasRating "5.0"^^xsd:float .
```

Comment: What do you mean by "optimize" it?  Does it run too slowly? Or are you trying to format it more nicely?

Comment: "It looks so bad" is a bit of an odd reason to optimize a query, are you worried about what it _looks_ like?  Typically optimizing a query is about getting the best execution performance, though occassionally you can of course rewrite a query for better readability. So what outcome are you after here?

Comment: I am actually worried about how does it looks like. Maybe there are better solution, rather that my query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slight alternative to Joshua's query which should work on your Sesame database (which is an older version that contains a bug in property path evaluation):

```
SELECT ?p ?p1 ?genre WHERE {

  ?p  movies:hasRated [ movies:ratedMovie [ movies:hasGenre ?genre ];
                        movies:hasRating ?rating ].

  ?p1 foaf:knows ?p ;
      movies:hasRated [ movies:ratedMovie [ movies:hasGenre ?genre ];
                        movies:hasRating ?ratingp1 ].
  FILTER (?p = movies:user1 )
}
GROUP BY ?p ?p1 ?genre
HAVING (abs (AVG(?rating)-AVG(?ratingp1))<1.0)
```

As you see, similar to Joshua's query, except that here we do not use property path but use a further blank node, and also do not use a values clause (which also has a bug in 2.7.8).

I would really recommend that you update your Sesame database though - 2.7.8 was released in 2013, we've fixed a ton of bugs since then (not to mention significantly improved the query editor in the workbench - it now has nice colors and autocomplete features).

Answer (score 3):

iI don't see that your query is particularly poorly optimized, but since you mention that it *looks* bad, I expect that you're asking about formatting.   It's OK, as it is now, but you could remove a few of the variables and use blank nodes and property paths instead.  E.g.:

```sql
SELECT ?p ?p1 ?genre WHERE {
  values ?p { movies:user1 }

  ?p  movies:hasRated [ movies:ratedMovie/movies:hasGenre ?genre ;
                        movies:hasRating ?rating ].

  ?p1 foaf:knows ?p ;
      movies:hasRated [ movies:ratedMovie/movies:hasGenre ?genre ;
                        movies:hasRating ?ratingp1 ].
}
GROUP BY ?p ?p1 ?genre
HAVING (abs (AVG(?rating)-AVG(?ratingp1))<1.0)
```

Comment: Oh FFS Joshua, get some sleep will ya? :)

Comment: @JeenBroekstra This was pretty much [the answer I posted to nlimit's previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30762389/1281433);  I'm not really sure why nlimit didn't just adopt that.  But I think we owe each other a mutual upvote, having produced almost identical answers. :)  But I do prefer the **values** over **filter**, in case some unoptimized query engine handles **values** better.

Comment: No worries, good answer, upvoted, I just vented my frustration at writing a pretty much identical answer about 1 minute after you writing yours... Anyway, removed it.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra Well, it can be a good sign when people produce almost identical results. (I remember at university, one labmate and I whom I worked very closely with actually had compare answers a few times to make sure they were *different* enough because we'd developed very similar coding styles.)

Comment: @nlimits "The proposed solution is not working"  Two questions: 1) Why did you mark the answer as accepted, then? 2)  What's not working about it?  Modulo typos that might have crept in, it's the same query as the one in the question, which you said does work.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor it seems to be an error with the framework (Sesame), so that [ movies:ratedMove/movies:hasGenre ?genre ;
                        movies:hasRating ?rating ] is not working. I accepted, because logically it seems to be correct)

Comment: @nlimits sparql.org's query validator accepts it, but I do kind of recall a spec bug about property paths in blank nodes a while back... let me see if I can find a reference on that.  UPDATE: nope, it wasn't the thing I was thinking about.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor http://kilda.informatik.uni-freiburg.de:8080/openrdf-workbench/repositories/pubs/query here is the engine

Comment: There was a typo in the query: `movies:ratedMove` should be `movies:ratedMovie`. I've confirmed that it works as expected after correcting that. Edited your answer.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra Thanks!  How did you confirm, by the way?  I see the endpoint link that OP mentioned, but I still don't know what the "movies" prefix is supposed to be.

Comment: Thanks, but still the result is empty table

Comment: I just added an `example.org` namespace to the data snippet and uploaded it into my own sesame store.

Comment: @nlimits I don't know if this will solve the problem but I notice that your endpoint runs a rather old version of Sesame (2.7.8). You might want to consider updating to the latest 2.7 release (2.7.15), or even straight to 2.8.3. The particular bug you may have hit here is https://openrdf.atlassian.net/browse/SES-2024, which was fixed in release 2.7.11

Comment: Alternatively, see my answer for a slightly rewritten query that should work on your version of Sesame.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor by the way the link the OP sent to "the engine" is actually a link to the Workbench client, and it points at the wrong database (pubs, instead of movies) - which is why it doesn't show the movies prefix. If you go to http://kilda.informatik.uni-freiburg.de:8080/openrdf-workbench/repositories/movies/query instead you can try out the query directly on his data.

Comment: @nlimits I don't know if you realize, by the way, but you're posting links to an unprotected interface to your database on a public forum. And it's not just read access - anybody can go in and delete your databases and/or add data to them.